# Files transfer using cmd from windows to linux server

Tags: python, linux, windows, unix, jython

I want to transfer a file from windows env to linux env. 
am using hyperion fdmee(windows env) which as scripting language of jython from this windows env where i have to create a batch script to transfer the file to linux env.

Comment: Use pscp [options] source [source...] [user@]host:target

Comment: Hi, can you please give one example?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: import os
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() 
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()..am trying to use above command. whether i need to import paramiko library? or by defualt python has this library?

Answer (score -1):

pscp [path of local file] username@10.80.14.249:[path of remote directory]

Answer (score -1):

You can simply mount windows directory to Linux server and then you can use cp command to copy a file from mounted location to your location.